# Getting error on $.mobile.changePage(): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'trigger' of undefined

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, router

I have a JQM apps and I am incorporating Backbone.
Since my initial javascript code is huge, I am only extracting what I believe is problematic. 
I am following the advices and calls steps cited here:

- jqm-config.js from http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/03/using-backbone-js-with-jquery-mobile/
- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/backbone-require.html

I have a major problem, and this is the behaviour, the problem comes from this code:

```
 var r = Backbone.Router.extend
 router: ...    
    "page": "pageDisplay"
 ...
 pageDisplay: function(){
    c = new AView();      // Backbone.View    ...fetch() data...   
    $(c.el).page();       // Call to JQM to add its extra stuff; seems done correctly
    $.mobile.changePage( "#" + c.id, {changeHash: false});       // line 50
 }
```

When following the links of `<a href="#page" >`, I come as expected to the 
page "#page" properly processed.  But once there, if I click a `refresh`, which is indirectly reprocessed by the same router rule, I end up with the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'trigger' of undefined

I downloaded the jquery mobile development code and observed this:

> // JQM1.1.2 - Line #3772 Show a specific page in the page container.
>
> ```
>   $.mobile.changePage = function( toPage, options ) {
>
>   if ( isPageTransitioning ) { 
>      pageTransitionQueue.unshift(arguments );
>      return;      
>   }
>   var settings = $.extend( {}, $.mobile.changePage.defaults, options);
>
>   // Make sure we have a pageContainer to work with.      
>   settings.pageContainer = settings.pageContainer || $.mobile.pageContainer;
>   // Make sure we have a fromPage.        
>   settings.fromPage = settings.fromPage || $.mobile.activePage;
>                                               // Line #3788   
>   var mpc = settings.pageContainer,      // Line #3789        
>       pbcEvent = new $.Event("pagebeforechange" ),
>       triggerData = { toPage: toPage, options: settings };
>   // Let listeners know we're about to change the current page.
>   mpc.trigger( pbcEvent, triggerData );      // Line #3794
> ```

The `Uncaught TypeError` is caused by Line #3794, because `mpc` is `undefined`.
So, from JQM, In the Chrome inspector, I can see also that `settings.fromPage` is `undefined` and `settings.pageContainer` is `undefined`.  I kind of imagine, that JQM cannot make an assumption on the fromPage, and therefore, cannot proceed on my refresh.  All the options I have tried on the $mobile.changePage() have not succeed.  I am out of ideas.

**UPDATE**/  Online site with the minimum to reproduce the problem:
         apartindex, [access the website with the bug](http://www.apartindex.com)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be related on how you boot with a first page in backbone and jquery mobile on a page refresh...

Comment: No idea... Is it possible to get a link to the live project?

Comment: I should be able to remove alot of stuff and put it on the web, by tomorrow, stay tuned.

Comment: ok, the website and its problem is in the following temporarily website: [link](http://www.apartindex.com). I hope can help feedbacks.

Comment: Hum... seems to be related to a know dependency on google analytics... I am looking into it.  I put my google analytics in comment and it solves the problem.  I am just out of my mind, it cannot be only that.  And why ?

Comment: **Nop, the problem persist**, it might be because google analytics add/removes some delays on the javascript engine which makes it ok on a small network but remains on an internet production environment.  I hope somebody can find my code error ?

Comment: If the problem does not appear at first, just refresh and observe the javascript console in your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dextoInit` function that calls the router code is called in `$(document).ready()` which does not guarantee that the jQuery mobile page has actually been set up successfully. But the router code calls `$.mobile.changePage` which depends on jQuery Mobile being initialized.

Putting it into `mobileinit` or `pageinit` should work.

(Unfortunately I can't modify the code and test it easily.)

Comment: I tried that before without succes.  I will retry it within the hour.  I wish to put this site on jsfiddle but I did not know how to manage multiple files on it.

Comment: I have been trying many things, but again, without success.  The dependencies seems ok, as seen on the network tab from chrome inspector.  I am binding on mobileinit, has proposed.  I stopped binding on pageinit, cause, the $.mobile. settings must be set prior a first pageinit. Arghhh, I do not have hair anymore.  The new code in back on the site apartindex.com.

Comment: @Mathias-Dev `mobileinit` is triggered before the page is set up, so it would make  sense if it doesn't work. Have you tried putting the settings there and the `Backbone.history.start();` into `pageinit`?

Comment: I did tried with `pageinit`, but it was called twice, and from my research, this happens when you have more than one page loaded at a time.  I do not have this scenario, but, I tried to avoid this second anomaly.  Since I made so many changes, I will try again with some different configuration of `pageinit`.

Answer (score 0):

Although, this fix it for the moment, it does have drawbacks.  See below.

```
$(document).bind("pageinit", function(){
   console.log('bindtomobileinit: event pageinit received');
   if ( !window.AppNode.router ){
      window.AppNode.router = new AppNode.singletons.router();
      console.log("mobileRouter.js: Starting b history");
      console.log('mobileRouter.js: About to launch Backbone history');
      Backbone.history.start();  
   }

});
```

Registering to **`pageinit`** has a weird effect of being **fired twice**.  I see that 2 nodes have been added to the Dom: the default "loading" `jquery mobile div` (related to pageinit:1), and my `data-role page` (pageinit:2).  So on a **"refresh browser click"**, my  situation leaves me waiting for a first `pageinit`, creating an unexpected jquery mobile dom element (a default page created to display the waiting JQM circle animation), which trigger the router creation, and allows the Backbone.history call which then deal with my "" home page.  The second `pageinit` do not interfere with the settings since I execute it only once.

I am really disappointed by this setup.  I will leave this question for now, since it does sort of work.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the source of the problem to be jquery-mobile version 1.3.0.  When I fall back to either JSM 1.2.0 or 1.2.1, the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'trigger' of undefined" problem goes away.

BTW, I am not using Backbone.

Answer (score 0):

I had fixed this problem by using method append(), but not html()

```
$('body').append(view.render().$el);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by changing the page data property from "data-role" to "data-mobile-page" as what is referenced in line 4042 of jqm 1.3.2

```
fromPage.data( "mobile-page" )._trigger( "beforehide", null, { nextPage: toPage } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting

```
$.mobile.autoInitializePage = true;
```

In your jquery mobile config file, some place like:

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {...});
```

May help.